# What are the requirements for contributing a pull request to the Ethereum web3.js repository?

Tags: web3js

I would like to make a pull request to the web3.js repository (https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js). Are there any requirements, guidelines, etc.
I haven't been able to find any information regarding contributions or a developers guide for web3.js, unlike go-ethereum (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Developers-Guide)